# Confusion about instance in an interface

Tags: java, osgi

I'm trying to learn OGSi framework (Equinox distribution).

I have registered my service, but I'm confused about a piece of code that I've copied:

```
IAgendaService service = new AgendaService();
```

What does this line of code mean?

I think that in the service object, there are the `IAgendaService` methods that I've implemented in `AgendaService`, but I' m not sure about this.

Could it be a sort of upcating? (I know that it can't be because there is no inheritance, but I try to find something similar to compare)

Comment: it is simply a variable of type `IAgendaService` that is assigned from a concret type. Here I talk about my background (c#) but you cannot instanciate a variable from an interface since the interface doesn't provide any implementation

Comment: I know, I'm a C# programmer for this cause I'm a bit confused. I think it could be an Anonymous class but I prefer wait a java expert

Comment: I think you question is unclear. I mean this line would be the same in c# so I don't get what confuse you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AgendaService is a class that implements the IAgendaService interface.  That line is the equivalent to the following:

```
IAgendaService service;
AgendaService agendaService = new AgendaService();
service = agendaService;
```

The service variable can reference any object that implements IAgendaService.  In the example above, service is referencing an instance of the AgendaService class.

AgendaSevice implements IAgendaService, so it must contain all the methods in the IAgendaService interface.  You can call any method in the IAgendaService interface using the service object.  If you attempt to call an AgendaService method, then it will result in a compilation error.

To help clarify here is an example.  The processing in the main class will result in the same output.

```
public interface IAgendaService {
    public void method1();
    public void method2();
}

public class AgendaService implements IAgendaService {
    private String instanceName;

    public AgendaService(String instanceName) {
        this.instanceName = instanceName;
    }

    public void method1() {
        System.out.println(instanceName + " - method1");
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println(instanceName + " - method2");
    }

    public void method3() {
        System.out.println(instanceName + " - method3");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       AgendaService agendaService = new AgendaService("1");
       agendaService.method1(); // prints 1 - method1
       agendaService.method2(); // prints 1 - method2
       agendaService.method3(); // prints 1 - method3

       IAgendaService iAgendaService = agendaService;
       iAgendaService.method1(); // prints 1 - method1
       iAgendaService.method2(); // prints 1 - method2
       iAgendaService.method3(); // compile error because IAgendaService doesn't have a method3
    }
}
```